# useReducer dispatch called in a wrong order

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm writing a hook which is supposed to help me with async promises. Now I stumbled upon a very weird issue. Basically I call dispatch twice with two actions ("actionA" and "actionB") in a specific order. One action ("actionA") is called in a useEffect cleanup callback. I expect it to work like this: "state1" -> "actionA" -> "state2" -> "actionB" -> "state3". But instead I'm getting something like "state1" -> "actionB" -> "unexpected state 4", "state1" -> "actionA" -> "state2".

I attach full working example to this question. Click button twice. I'm getting logs like

```
reducer cancelled(10) start(8) pending(11)
dispatch cancel 8
dispatch reject 8
reducer pending(11) reject(8) rejected(15)
reducer pending(11) cancel(8) cancelled(17)
reducer cancelled(17) start(13) pending(18)
```

So it's clear that `dispatch cancel 8` and `dispatch reject 8` are called in a correct order. But instead of getting something like `reducer pending(11) cancel(8) cancelled(17)`, `cancelled(17) reject(8) cancelled(17)` like I expected, I'm getting those dispatches in a wrong order and they act on the same state! It's like they fork the state. I don't understand why is this happening. Component itself is not unmounting. Is there something special about useEffect cleanup function in regards to state change?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script
      crossorigin
      src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone@7/babel.js"
    ></script>

    <script
      crossorigin
      src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"
    ></script>
    <script
      crossorigin
      src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"
    ></script>
    <script type="text/babel">
      const { useEffect, useReducer } = React;
      const { createRoot } = ReactDOM;

      const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
      createRoot(rootElement).render(<App />);

      function App() {
        const [param, setParam] = React.useState(1);

        const result = usePromise(
          (signal) => {
            return myFetch(param, signal);
          },
          [param]
        );

        const handleClick = () => {
          setParam((param) => param + 1);
        };

        return (
          <>
            <div>param: {param}</div>
            <div>result: {JSON.stringify(result)}</div>
            <button onClick={handleClick}>click</button>
          </>
        );
      }

      function myFetch(param, signal) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          const timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
            resolve(`result ${param}`);
          }, 1000);
          signal.addEventListener("abort", () => {
            clearTimeout(timeoutId);
            reject("aborted");
          });
        });
      }

      let nextId = 1;

      function reducer(state, action) {
        const id = nextId++;
        let nextState = state;
        switch (action.type) {
          case "start":
            if (state.status === "created" || state.status === "cancelled") {
              nextState = {
                id,
                promiseId: action.promiseId,
                status: "pending",
              };
            }
            break;

          case "resolve":
            if (
              state.status === "pending" &&
              state.promiseId === action.promiseId
            ) {
              nextState = { id, status: "fulfilled", value: action.value };
            }
            break;

          case "reject":
            if (
              state.status === "pending" &&
              state.promiseId === action.promiseId
            ) {
              nextState = { id, status: "rejected", reason: action.reason };
            }
            break;

          case "cancel":
            nextState = { id, status: "cancelled" };
        }

        console.log(
          "reducer",
          `${state.status}(${state.id})`,
          `${action.type}(${action.promiseId})`,
          `${nextState.status}(${nextState.id})`
        );

        return nextState;
      }

      function usePromise(promiseFunction, deps) {
        const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, {
          id: nextId++,
          status: "created",
        });
        useEffect(() => {
          const promiseId = nextId++;
          const abortController = new AbortController();
          const promise = promiseFunction(abortController.signal);
          dispatch({ type: "start", promiseId });
          promise.then(
            (value) => {
              dispatch({ type: "resolve", promiseId, value });
            },
            (reason) => {
              console.log("dispatch reject", promiseId);
              dispatch({ type: "reject", promiseId, reason });
            }
          );
          return () => {
            console.log("dispatch cancel", promiseId);
            dispatch({ type: "cancel", promiseId });
            abortController.abort();
          };
        }, deps);
        return state;
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem here is the useEffect cleanup function being called asynchronously, after the component has already re-rendered and the second dispatch has already been called.

We can use useRef on the usePromise hook to keep track of whether the component is still mounted, and check that value in the cleanup function before calling the second dispatch.

```
function usePromise(promiseFunction, deps) {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, {
    id: nextId++,
    status: "created",
  });
  const promiseRef = useRef(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    const promiseId = nextId++;
    const abortController = new AbortController();
    const promise = promiseFunction(abortController.signal);
    promiseRef.current = promiseId;
    dispatch({ type: "start", promiseId });
    promise.then(
      (value) => {
        if (promiseRef.current === promiseId) {
          dispatch({ type: "resolve", promiseId, value });
        }
      },
      (reason) => {
        if (promiseRef.current === promiseId) {
          console.log("dispatch reject", promiseId);
          dispatch({ type: "reject", promiseId, reason });
        }
      }
    );
    return () => {
      console.log("dispatch cancel", promiseId);
      if (promiseRef.current === promiseId) {
        dispatch({ type: "cancel", promiseId });
      }
      abortController.abort();
    };
  }, deps);
  return state;
}
```